# how to convert \u00000013\u0007 to utf8 human readable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this string that comes from a translation in java according to search this is unicode ***\u0000\u0013\u0007*** I need to be able to translate it to a readable text according to I saw is equivalent to 0197 ... but I need to do it in Python 3 I have searched and the solutions do not fit to the reality

I need this but in python https://www.tutorialspoint.com/convert-unicode-to-utf-8-in-java

Comment: Is this in a text file?

Comment: is a text string, this comes in a json

Comment: how do you know its 0197?

Comment: `str('\u0000\u0013\u0007')` returned `!!` for me. Is that what you meant by the solutions do not fit to the reality?

Comment: i need this ... but in python https://www.tutorialspoint.com/convert-unicode-to-utf-8-in-java

Comment: Why are you reading a Java tutorial if you want to get things done in python?

Comment: wouldn't the python eqivalent of `str.getBytes("UTF-8");` be `str.encode('utf-8')`?

Comment: @Wanja no ... please try it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the (decimal?) value of the bytes that represent these unicode points, for a certain encoding.

Using the UTF-8 encoding, you can do the following:

```
>>> for byte in '\u0000\u0013\u0007'.encode('utf-8'):
...   print(byte)
...
0
19
7
```

The part `'\u0000\u0013\u0007'.encode('utf-8')` returns the unicode string as a byte string for UTF-8 encoding. To get the individual numbers, transform it to a list:

```
>>> '\u0000\u0013\u0007'.encode('utf-8')
b'\x00\x13\x07'
>>> list('\u0000\u0013\u0007'.encode('utf-8'))
[0, 19, 7]
```